# How do you use OptionParser to open a file with command-line options?

Tags: ruby, command-line-arguments, optionparser

I'm getting this error when trying to print line from a file via command-line options

```
no implicit conversion of true into String (TypeError)
from threat_detection.rb:64:in 'new'
from threat_detection.rb:64:in '<main>'
```

If I use the file name instead of `options[:config_file]` it prints the lines of the file, as expected.

```
if options[:config_file]
  File.new(options[:config_file], 'r').each { |params| puts params }
end

if options[:host_file]
  File.new(options[:host_file], 'r').each { |host| puts host }
end
```

Comment: I do suspect `options[:config_file]` does not return name of the file but `true` value (probably just a flag option was passed to the script). You need to use proper hash/value holding a filename or fix a possible bug in option parser code.

Comment: please provide options parse code...

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are trying to use the [`OptionParser`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/optparse/rdoc/OptionParser.html) class in Ruby. Since it is not a part of the core library, make make sure to include the following at the top of your program:

```
require 'optparse'
```

Furthermore, make sure you are creating your options correctly:

```
options = {}

optparse = OptionParser.new do |opts|
  options[:config_file] = nil
  opts.on('-f', '--config-file', 'Enter the config file to open.') do
    options[:dry_run] = true
  end
end

optparse.parse!
```

When using a flag in command line, you are essentially setting a variable to `true` or `false`. For example, by default, `-v` (verbose) is set to `false` for most operations (like `rm`). Following the command and its optional flags are (sometimes required) command-line arguments, which is the filename in your case.

Calling your script should look similar to

```
$ ruby ./my_program.rb --config-file /path/to/some/file
       ^               ^             ^
       program         flag          argument
```

As you saw, an optparse option must be a boolean. You only want to open a file if the flag is present (option is true). Just a slight change is needed for your program to run:

```
if options[:config_file]
  File.new(ARGV[0], 'r').each { |params| puts params }
end
```

[`ARGV`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/ARGF.html#method-i-argv) is an array of all command-line arguments to your script (following flags). If you only include one argument, you will want the first element, or index 0 (`ARGV[0]`). All arguments are separated by spaces. So if you implement the same technique for `options[:host_file]`, you can use `ARGV[1]`.